# how to save multiple images in document folder by date and time

Tags: ios, objective-c, document

i want to save multiple images in document folder i am save image successful in document folder but my image is override i try to save images by date and time 
any help will appreciate,
 my code is

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    _imageview.image=[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_imageview.image);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
    NSString *Path = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:SS"];

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date]; 
    NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];

    [pngData writeToFile:Path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: You have to actually use `theData` string as part of the `Path`.

Comment: Also ":" is not allowed in file names. Check my answer please.

Comment: @Avt It's perfectly fine to have colons in a filename in iOS or OS X.

Comment: @rmaddy I have just tried on iOS Simulator and ":" in filenames was changed with "/".

Comment: @Avt I'll have to double check on a real iOS device but at the command line in OS X I had no problem creating a filename with a colon.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    _imageview.image=[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_imageview.image);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH_mm_SS"];

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date]; 
    NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];
    NSString *fileName = [theDate stringByAppendingString:@".png"];

    NSString *Path = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    [pngData writeToFile:Path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: It's best to provide an explanation along with your code. What was wrong? What does your code fix?

Comment: @rmaddy Sure. I always do so if answer really requires some explanations.

Comment: thanks Avt u really solved my problem i will thanks from my heart god bless u bro

Comment: please tell me how to retrive images from document folder